# xmpppy error connecting to gtalk

Tags: python, google-talk, xmpppy

I'm about to tear my hair out with this issue. I'm using the simplest code I can think of just to test xmppy and it fails again and again. I've used sendxmpp in the past, but am trying to migrate some server side scripts to, well, use python rather than piping output to sendxmpp.

Anyway: Here's the code:

```
import xmpp

user = "actual.user@gmail.com"
password = "actualPassword"
server = 'talk.google.com'

jid = xmpp.JID(user)
connection = xmpp.Client(server)
connection.connect()
```

And here's the resulting output:

```
Invalid debugflag given: always
Invalid debugflag given: nodebuilder
DEBUG: 
DEBUG: Debug created for /Users/ben/Desktop/PythonScripts/XMPP/xmpp/client.py
DEBUG:  flags defined: always,nodebuilder
DEBUG: socket       start Plugging <xmpp.transports.TCPsocket instance at 0x108daae60> into <xmpp.client.Client instance at 0x108daad88>
DEBUG: socket       warn  An error occurred while looking up _xmpp-client._tcp.talk.google.com
DEBUG: socket       start Successfully connected to remote host ('talk.google.com', 5222)
DEBUG: dispatcher   start Plugging <xmpp.dispatcher.Dispatcher instance at 0x108dbd050> into <xmpp.client.Client instance at 0x108daad88>
DEBUG: dispatcher   info  Registering namespace "unknown"
DEBUG: dispatcher   info  Registering protocol "unknown" as <class 'xmpp.protocol.Protocol'>(unknown)
DEBUG: dispatcher   info  Registering protocol "default" as <class 'xmpp.protocol.Protocol'>(unknown)
DEBUG: dispatcher   info  Registering namespace "http://etherx.jabber.org/streams"
DEBUG: dispatcher   info  Registering protocol "unknown" as <class 'xmpp.protocol.Protocol'>(http://etherx.jabber.org/streams)
DEBUG: dispatcher   info  Registering protocol "default" as <class 'xmpp.protocol.Protocol'>(http://etherx.jabber.org/streams)
DEBUG: dispatcher   info  Registering namespace "jabber:client"
DEBUG: dispatcher   info  Registering protocol "unknown" as <class 'xmpp.protocol.Protocol'>(jabber:client)
DEBUG: dispatcher   info  Registering protocol "default" as <class 'xmpp.protocol.Protocol'>(jabber:client)
DEBUG: dispatcher   info  Registering protocol "iq" as <class 'xmpp.protocol.Iq'>(jabber:client)
DEBUG: dispatcher   info  Registering protocol "presence" as <class 'xmpp.protocol.Presence'>(jabber:client)
DEBUG: dispatcher   info  Registering protocol "message" as <class 'xmpp.protocol.Message'>(jabber:client)
DEBUG: dispatcher   info  Registering handler <bound method Dispatcher.streamErrorHandler of <xmpp.dispatcher.Dispatcher instance at 0x108dbd050>> for "error" type-> ns->(http://etherx.jabber.org/streams)
DEBUG: dispatcher   warn  Registering protocol "error" as <class 'xmpp.protocol.Protocol'>(http://etherx.jabber.org/streams)
DEBUG: socket       sent  <?xml version='1.0'?>
  <stream:stream xmlns="jabber:client" to="talk.google.com" version="1.0" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" >
DEBUG: socket       got   <stream:stream from="talk.google.com" id="B0E6462206621A27" version="1.0" xmlns:stream="http://etherx.jabber.org/streams" xmlns="jabber:client">
  <stream:features>
  <starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls">
  <required/>
  </starttls>
  <mechanisms xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl">
  <mechanism>X-GOOGLE-TOKEN</mechanism>
  <mechanism>X-OAUTH2</mechanism>
  </mechanisms>
  </stream:features>
DEBUG: dispatcher   warn  Unknown stanza: features
DEBUG: dispatcher   ok    Dispatching unknown stanza with type-> props->[u'urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls', u'urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl'] id->None
DEBUG: tls          start Plugging <xmpp.transports.TLS instance at 0x108dbda28> into <xmpp.client.Client instance at 0x108daad88>
DEBUG: tls          ok    TLS supported by remote server. Requesting TLS start.
DEBUG: dispatcher   info  Registering handler <bound method TLS.StartTLSHandler of <xmpp.transports.TLS instance at 0x108dbda28>> for "proceed" type-> ns->(urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls)
DEBUG: dispatcher   warn  Registering namespace "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"
DEBUG: dispatcher   info  Registering protocol "unknown" as <class 'xmpp.protocol.Protocol'>(urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls)
DEBUG: dispatcher   info  Registering protocol "default" as <class 'xmpp.protocol.Protocol'>(urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls)
DEBUG: dispatcher   warn  Registering protocol "proceed" as <class 'xmpp.protocol.Protocol'>(urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls)
DEBUG: dispatcher   info  Registering handler <bound method TLS.StartTLSHandler of <xmpp.transports.TLS instance at 0x108dbda28>> for "failure" type-> ns->(urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls)
DEBUG: dispatcher   warn  Registering protocol "failure" as <class 'xmpp.protocol.Protocol'>(urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls)
DEBUG: socket       sent  <starttls xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-tls"/>
DEBUG: socket       got   <stream:error>
  <host-unknown xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams"/>
  <str:text xmlns:str="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams">Set the 'to' attribute of stream element to the domain part of the user's JID. Example: to='gmail.com'.</str:text>
  </stream:error>
  </stream:stream>
DEBUG: dispatcher   ok    Got http://etherx.jabber.org/streams/error stanza
DEBUG: dispatcher   ok    Dispatching error stanza with type-> props->[u'urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-streams'] id->None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sendXMPP.py", line 16, in <module>
    print connection.connect()
  File "/Users/ben/Desktop/PythonScripts/XMPP/xmpp/client.py", line 205, in connect
    while not self.TLS.starttls and self.Process(1): pass
  File "/Users/ben/Desktop/PythonScripts/XMPP/xmpp/dispatcher.py", line 303, in dispatch
    handler['func'](session,stanza)
  File "/Users/ben/Desktop/PythonScripts/XMPP/xmpp/dispatcher.py", line 215, in streamErrorHandler
    raise exc((name,text))
xmpp.protocol.HostUnknown: (u'host-unknown', u"Set the 'to' attribute of stream element to the domain part of the user's JID. Example: to='gmail.com'.")
```

What on earth am I doing wrong here?

Edit: Updated code to show changes.

New Code:

```
import xmpp

user = "actual.user@gmail.com"
password = "actualPassword"
server = 'talk.google.com'

jid = xmpp.JID(user)
connection = xmpp.Client(jid.getDomain())
connection.connect()
result = connection.auth(jid.getNode(), password,"TESTING")
```

New Error:

```
Invalid debugflag given: always
Invalid debugflag given: nodebuilder
DEBUG: 
DEBUG: Debug created for /Users/ben/Desktop/PythonScripts/XMPP/xmpp/client.py
DEBUG:  flags defined: always,nodebuilder
DEBUG: socket       start Plugging <xmpp.transports.TCPsocket instance at 0x1033c0e60> into <xmpp.client.Client instance at 0x1033c0d88>
DEBUG: socket       warn  An error occurred while looking up _xmpp-client._tcp.gmail.com
DEBUG: socket       error Failed to connect to remote host ('gmail.com', 5222): Operation timed out (60)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/ben/Desktop/PythonScripts/XMPP/xmpp/transports.py", line 133, in connect
    self._sock.connect((server[0], int(server[1])))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
DEBUG: socket       stop  Plugging <xmpp.transports.TCPsocket instance at 0x1033c0e60> out of <xmpp.client.Client instance at 0x1033c0d88>.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./sendXMPP.py", line 17, in <module>
    result = connection.auth(jid.getNode(), password,"LFY-client")
  File "/Users/ben/Desktop/PythonScripts/XMPP/xmpp/client.py", line 214, in auth
    while not self.Dispatcher.Stream._document_attrs and self.Process(1): pass
AttributeError: Client instance has no attribute 'Dispatcher'
```

Comment: A typo of server, sorry. Changed the code.

Comment: Umm, the updated traceback doesn't fit to the updated code at all - the error is in line 17, but the code only contains 7 lines. Could you post the [*actual* code you're running](http://sscce.org/)? Also make sure that your DNS server is correctly configured - it should be quite a few SRV records for `_xmpp-client._tcp.gmail.com`. If in doubt, set it to [8.8.8.8](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/).

Comment: The code I have update with should now compile. The only line that was missing was the connection.auth() line, which has now been added. I have checked to ensure (with nslookup) that I have DNS entries for the address. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Comment: Mmm, I can't reproduce the first error message. Can you provide a link to a packet dump (for example with [wireshark](http://wireshark.org/))?

Comment: My entire operating system refused to boot this morning (OSX) so I've set up my dev environment under bootcamp, and it works fine with Windows. In future I'll ensure I check on multiple environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not manually set a server - `xmpp.Client` will try to figure it out on its own:

```
import xmpp

jid = xmpp.JID("actual.user@gmail.com")
connection = xmpp.Client(jid.getDomain())
connection.connect()
```

should work fine.

Comment: That was my original thought as well, however I couldn't even get as far as I did when using that method. I've updated my original question to show the output of what happens when I use that identical code.

Comment: I've also accepted this answer, as without my environmental issues, the application would still not have worked without this correction. Thanks :-)